# Responsive sidenav with screen detection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm working on an angular project with the material library, and I'm facing a problem, I need to implement a method for the way to open the sidenav, that is, the default is for it to use mode="side", but for smaller devices, I need stick with mode="over", I saw some ideas with angular material2 but I believe it doesn't work anymore, because the tags and imports are no longer available.

sidebar.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidebar-sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #snav mode="side" fixedTopGap="56" opened="false">
      <app-side-navbar></app-side-navbar>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content class="router-container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

I tried to implement some old functions with angular material in version 2, but some tags and functions don't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Media Observer](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/MediaObserver) to get the current device's screen size.

```
isSmallDevice(): boolean { 
 return this.mediaObserver.isActive('xs') || 
 this.mediaObserver.isActive('sm');
}
```

Then, you can use this to switch between different modes in your template:

```
<mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="isSmallDevice() ? 'over' : 'side'" fixedTopGap="56" opened="false">
      <app-side-navbar></app-side-navbar>
</mat-sidenav>
```

Comment: ow thanks for the support bud! Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

this is my resolution of the problem.

code html =

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidebar-sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #snav [mode]="modo" fixedTopGap="56" opened="false">
      <app-side-navbar></app-side-navbar>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content class="router-container">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

ts class =

```
modo: any = "side";
  //opened: any = "false";

updateModo() {
    (window.innerWidth <= 850) ? this.modo = "over" : this.modo = "side";
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).